# Posting Smash Ultimate replay videos directly to YouTube

Tags: nintendo-switch, super-smash-bros-ultimate

Is it possible to upload Smash Ultimate replay videos directly to YouTube?

The default Switch workflow seems to involve saving replay videos to an SD Card and using a computer to manually upload the videos to YouTube.

But *Super Smash Bros. for Wii U* replays could be uploaded directly to YouTube from the console itself:

> Most battles in Super Smash Bros. for Wii U can be saved as a replay by pressing the Y Button. Saved replays can be shared within the game and can also **be posted on YouTube** and the Replay Viewing Community on Miiverse.
>
> https://www.smashbros.com/wiiu-3ds/us/howto/entry14.html

[image: direct to YouTube]

Is an equivalent feature available in *Super Smash Bros. Ultimate* on the Nintendo Switch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the Super Smash Bros. Ultimate **3.0.0** update, replay videos can be uploaded directly to YouTube via the Miiverse / Smash World sharing service and collected on the Nintendo Switch Online mobile app.

This technique **still requires an SD Card** in your Switch to save videos. It does eliminate though the steps of removing the SD Card from your Switch, plugging it into your computer, manually posting to YouTube, etc.

You will need to be signed in to the various Nintendo online accounts.

1. Save a replay after a match.
2. Go to **Vault > Replays > Replay Data**. Select a replay and **Convert to Video** to save the replay as a video onto your SD Card.

   - NOTE: ignore the **Post** button when inspecting a replay. It appears to be non-functional. You cannot currently post/share a replay directly.
3. Go to **Vault > Replays > Video** and select the just-created video. Select **Post** to share this replay to Miiverse / Smash World. Nintendo uses YouTube as the backing store for videos, so it will now take a few minutes to upload the video from your Switch directly to YouTube.
4. Open the Nintendo Switch Online mobile app on your phone. Select **Smash Ultimate > Profile > Posts**. Once they have fully uploaded, your replay videos will appear here.
5. Select a replay video. Click the **Share** arrow icon. **Copy** the link.
6. Open this link in a web browser. The video will have been added as an unlisted video on the official Super Smash Bros. Ultimate YouTube account.
7. Either share this link directly, or use something like [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) to download the video and splice/re-upload it to your own YouTube account.

[image: Smash World uploads]

Answer (score 1):

There is a way.

1. Go to Replays, and click on the replay you want and click Convert to
   Video.
2. Once it is finished making the video, take your microSD card out
3. Put the microSD on your computer or get a microSD to SD adapter and insert that way.
4. Save the video on your computer.
5. Log in to your YouTube account and post it from there.
6. Watch your video gain success on YouTube.

Comment: Yes, you can connect the SD card to your computer and manually upload. This question is more about any automatic way to upload directly from your Switch.

Comment: Not even 'more', but '*all* about automatic ways to upload videos directly'.